# Post Views / Hit Counter Problem?

Tags: database, count, phpmyadmin, views

I have decide to use WordPress as a CMS to my 5 moths old website. I have already added all previous posts to my new site ( WordPress ). But now I need to change view counts to previous views counts. I can't find `hit_count` or `views_count` from PhpMyAdmin database. How to change views count number manually on WordPress? Please help.

> function.php

```
<?php
// function to display number of posts.
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return '0 View';
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}

// function to count views.
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}

// Add it to a column in WP-Admin - (Optional)
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_column_views');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_column_views',5,2);
function posts_column_views($defaults){
    $defaults['post_views'] = __('Views');
    return $defaults;
}
function posts_custom_column_views($column_name, $id){
 if($column_name === 'post_views'){
        echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
    }
}
?>
```

---

> single.php

```
<?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

Comment: your `setPostViews(get_the_ID());` function will update your view by 1 each time it runs. For you to set a views manually you need to create a new function to do so. Your existing functions don't have that feature.

Comment: please can I have the function code? I'm new to WordPress.

Comment: Check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following functionto set views manually

```
function setPostViewsManually($postID, $viewCount) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $viewCount);
}
```

You can run this code by

```
<?php setPostViewsManually(get_the_ID(), 1234); ?>
```

The above code will set the view to '1234' for the current post. Run this function carefully else your new views will always be '1234' because this function will keep running every time.

Just use it once and remove the code.